# Sharing a Queue created within a process - Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wish to have a list of Queue's shared between processes. The idea is from a "main" process, I can pipe whatever information I want to one of the other processes, but the number of other processes aren't determined.

**I cannot create the Queue in the "main" process**. I am simulating a decentralised system and creating the Queue in the main process does not fit this paradigm. As such, the Queue's must be created within the other processes.

This poses a difficulty, as I can't find how to share these Queue's with the main process. I have a managed list using `multiprocessing.Manager`, but if I append a `multiprocess.Queue` to it, I get:

> RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes
> through inheritance

Appending a standard data type such as an integer works just fine.

MRE below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

class test:

    def __init__(self, qlist):
        self.qlist = qlist

        self.q = mp.Queue()
        qlist.append(4)
        self.next = None
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            val = self.q.get()

            if val == 1:
                p = mp.Process(target = test, args=(qlist, ))
                p.start()
            else:
                print(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = mp.Manager()
    qlist = manager.list()

    p = mp.Process(target = test, args=(qlist, ))
    p.start()

    sleep(0.5)
    print(qlist)

    p.join()
```

The idea would be in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` code, I could look through the `qlist` and select one of the Queues to pipe information to, such as: `qlist[2].put(1)` to add a `test` object or `qlist[3].put("Hello")` to print "Hello".

The best case scenario would rather be to have a list of `test` objects (where the `test` object has its `self.q` attribute for accessing it's Queue) that I could access from the "main" process, but I'm even less sure of how to do that hence why I'm asking about the Queue's.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create queue instances in the main process; this occurs in your `test.__init__` method with the statement `self.q = mp.Queue()`, which is running in the main process. The problem is that a multiprocessing queue cannot be added to a managed list. Here is your program, slightly modified where it does not attempt to add the queues to a managed list. I have also made your `test` class (now renamed `Test`) to be a subclass of `Process` and it will now terminate:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, value):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.value = value
        self.q = mp.Queue()
        self.q.put(value)
        self.next = None

    def run(self):
        value = self.q.get()
        print('value = ', value)
        value -= 1
        if value > 0:
            p = Test(value).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Test(4).start()
```

Prints:

```
value =  4
value =  3
value =  2
value =  1
```

If you want to maintain a list of objects, then it would be better if `Test` is not a subclass of `Process`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test():
    def __init__(self, lst, value):
        lst.append(self)
        self.lst = lst
        self.value = value
        self.q = mp.Queue()
        self.q.put(value)
        self.next = None

    def run(self):
        value = self.q.get()
        print('value = ', value)
        value -= 1
        if value > 0:
            test = Test(self.lst, value)
            p = mp.Process(target=test.run).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    lst = manager.list()
    test = Test(lst, 4)
    p = mp.Process(target=test.run).start()
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
value =  4
value =  3
value =  2
value =  1
[<__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000028E6DAD5DC0>, <__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000028E6DAD5FA0>, <__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000028E6DAD5E50>, <__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000028E6DAD5D90>]
```

**But here is a big BUT:**

Each of those objects "live" in a different address space and the references can only have meaning when accessed from the original address space they were created in. So this is pretty useless:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test():
    def __init__(self, lst, value):
        lst.append(self)
        self.lst = lst
        self.value = value
        self.q = mp.Queue()
        self.q.put(value)
        self.next = None

    def run(self):
        value = self.q.get()
        print('value = ', value)
        value -= 1
        if value > 0:
            test = Test(self.lst, value)
            p = mp.Process(target=test.run).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    lst = manager.list()
    test = Test(lst, 4)
    p = mp.Process(target=test.run).start()
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    print(test, test.__class__, test.value)
    print(lst)
    for elem in lst:
        print(type(elem))
        print(elem.value)
```

Prints:

```
value =  4
value =  3
value =  2
value =  1
<__main__.Test object at 0x0000020E52E6A640> <class '__main__.Test'> 4
[<__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000016827704DC0>, <__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000016827704FA0>, <__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000016827704250>, <__mp_main__.Test object at 0x0000016827704D90>]
<class '__main__.Test'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Ron\test\test.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(elem.value)
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'value'
```